# override operator[] and call method

Tags: c++

I implemented `SpareArray` class. It's a big one, so there is no sense to show it all, but what is important is that is has `insert` method, which makes it possible to insert values at any index (from zero to "infinity"). So, my client code may look like so:

```
auto arr = new SpareArray<int>{};
arr.insert(100, 1);
```

The above code inserts value `1` at index `100`. Now, I want to be able to use square brakets notation to get the same result:

```
auto arr = new SpareArray<int>{};
arr[100] = 1; //I want this line to internally call arr.insert(100, 1);
```

So, how can `operator[]` be difined to internally call `insert` method? I need this call, because `insert` method has some business logic and I want this business logic to take place also in this case (in case of `[]`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: @TheDude. I address a concrete issue. You could say, that my question is a possible duplicate of what can be found in C++ reference. IMHO. I may be wrong.

Comment: And what do you want to happen when the client doesn't assign a value, when it reads one that isn't there?

Comment: And why can't you simply use your `insert()` function encapsulated in that operator overload? Mind to elaborate about that please?

Comment: Yes, this can be solved just with operator overloading.

Comment: So calling `cout << arr[100]` is expected to do what?

Comment: When it does not assign, I do not need to call `insert`.

Comment: Obviously,  but `arr[100]` has to have *some* value. That's according to the language itself.

Comment: @manni66. It will just print a value at this index.

Comment: @Jacobian You can do as done with some standard containers, have a `const` and a non `const`version.

Comment: And when you didn’t insert one before?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users? - Meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/5267751)

Comment: When it did not insert one, it will print a default value (business logic of this SpareArray, where default values are not stored).

Comment: So why can't you just insert the default value, and return a reference to it for modification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a proxy that does the final call to `insert` and acts as a wrapper around an element of your array.

```
template<typename T>
struct Proxy {
  Proxy(SpareArray<T> &This, std::size_t Index) : This(This), Index(Index) {}

  T &operator=(const T &Value) {
    This.insert(Index, Value);
    return This.get(Index); // or however you get an element
  }

  operator T&() { return This.get(Index); }
  operator const T&() const { return This.get(Index); }

private:
  SpareArray<T> &This;
  std::size_t Index;
};
```

For simplicity, I didn't add more but I would expect such a class to have proper `noexcept` semantics and a move assignment operator, for example. You also might want to make sure that you delete the copy constructors and such.

Comment: Thank you, sir! I got the idea and will check it.

Comment: Would you be so kind to show how this proxy can be used inside some arbitrary class `SpareArray`? Just an idea would be enough. Now when I try to make it a friend class inside SpareArray and return it from operator[] override, I get a ton of error messages.

Comment: @Jacobian Why does the proxy have to be a friend? What are the error messages? I can only guess because there are lots of things that could be wrong.

Comment: I will address it in a new question, that I'm just about to ask at SO.

Comment: If you have some time, please, have a look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608414/templated-proxy-design-pattern

Comment: Sorry for bothering you once again. I have a tiny question. Now, this construct started to work: `auto arr = new SpareArray<int>{}; arr[100] = 1;`. But this one stopped working - `std::cout << arr[100] << std::endl;`. Even though, my `SpareArray` class has such an overload: `T const& operator[] (int index) const {...}`. It seems like compiler still calls here proxied version of `operator[]`. Probably, you know what may be wrong with that.

Comment: @Jacobian Do what I did, because it seems like you didn't: Always return the proxy object, and provide a conversion operator inside the proxy object so that it implicitly converts itself to the element.