# Templated Proxy design pattern

Tags: c++, templates, declaration, forward-declaration

I have a simple and reproducible code, which looks like so:

```
template <typename T>
class Proxy {
private:
    Wrap<T> &self; // If I comment this, it will work
public:
    Proxy() {}
};

template <typename T>
class Wrap {
    T *p;
public:
    Proxy<T> foo() {
        return Proxy<T>();
    }
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is:

> 'Wrap' does not name a type

If I comment `Wrap<T> &self`, then it will work, but this is not what I need. I need `Wrap<T>` to be a member of `Proxy` class. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Declare it before `Proxy`.

Comment: Then I get `Proxy does not name a type`.

Comment: Declaration isn't the same as a definition.

Comment: Thank you, Mario! I got it!

Answer (score 5):

You could add [forward declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Forward_declaration) of `Wrap` before the class definition of `Proxy`, otherwise the compiler can't know that it's the name of a class template. It's worth noting that reference data member doesn't require the type to be [complete type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type), so forward declaration is enough here.

```
// forward declaration
template <typename T>
class Wrap;

template <typename T>
class Proxy {
private:
    Wrap<T> &self;
public:
    Proxy() {}
};
```

BTW the following issue would be that the reference data member `self` is not initialized.

[LIVE of Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7cQWYMST2ybUHSO6)

> error: constructor for 'Proxy' must explicitly initialize the reference member 'self'

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a forward declaration:

```
template<class T> class Wrap;

template <typename T>
class Proxy {
private:
    Wrap<T> &self;
public:
    Proxy() {}
};

template <typename T>
class Wrap {
    T *p;
public:
    Proxy<T> foo() {
        return Proxy<T>();
    }
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The code is just copied from the OP's question. But you still need to pay a attention to member `Wrap<T> &self`. As a reference, it should be initialized in constructor.

Comment: Thank you, sir! I did not know such a concept as "forward declaration".